# Using Rollup, ES output mode and gzip plugin, dynamic imports reference the JS file rather than the .gz.js file

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, rollup

I'm using Rollup to output my bundle as ES6 modules:

```
        output: {
            format: 'es',
            dir: `dist`,
            sourcemap: true,
        },
```

I'm also using the gzip plugin to generate `.gz.js` versions of my chunks along with their `.js` counterpart:

```
plugins: [
...
                gzipPlugin({
                    fileName: (fileName) => {
                        const name = fileName.split('.');
                        name.splice(-1, 0, 'gz');
                        return name.join('.');
                    },
                }),
...
]
```

e.g.
[image]

However, in both the outputted chunk as well as its gzipped version, the import statement references the `.js` file rather than the `.gz.js` file.

[image: app.min.js]

**Using Rollup config/plugins, how can I make sure the outputted files contains an import reference for the proper `.gz.js` files?**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by creating a Rollup plugin loosely based on the [rewrite-imports plugin](https://github.com/elmsln/rollup-plugin-rewrite-imports/blob/master/index.js). It replaces all instances of `.js` to `.gz.js` in dynamic imports:

```
const MagicString = require('magic-string');

function rewriteGzipImports() {
    // match dynamic imports with .js but not .gz.js
    const patternDImport = new RegExp(/"\.\/([\w\-.]+)\.js(?<!\.gz\.js)"/, 'mg');
    return {
        name: 'rewriteImports',
        renderChunk(code) {
            const magicString = new MagicString(code);
            let hasReplacements = false;
            let match;
            let start;
            let end;
            let replacement;

            function replaceImport() {
                hasReplacements = true;
                start = match.index + 3;
                end = start + match[1].length;
                replacement = String(match[1].replace(match[1], match[1] + '.gz'));
                magicString.overwrite(start, end, replacement);
            }

            // work against dynamic imports
            while (match = patternDImport.exec(code)) {
                replaceImport();
            }

            if (!hasReplacements) {
                return null;
            }
            return { code: magicString.toString() };
        }
    };
}
```